# Python Iterating Over a List Queue - Removing Duplicates with a Slowdown

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sockets, queue

Clients send in data through a socket. The data is parsed up, and placed into lists.

This works fine.

Sometimes it contains duplicate data and I want to replace the old data with this data so I .pop() it out  and append in the new data.

This works fine... for a while.

There's a slowdown somewhere. I'm judging the speed on a pretty consistent amount of data. It speeds through it all to start with and lasts about 10 minutes or so. In that time it's had to constantly clear old matches and the list size has been around the same.

But then the console becomes a fairly slow wall of "removing dupe:" when it was flying through that amount before.

And because that takes time more gets added to the queue and it becomes a never ending cycle which it can't catch up on.

Snippet of current code:

```
def QDUmp(): #Runs as a thread
    while 1:
        while not q.empty():

            print q.get()

            XMLdataparse = []
            del XMLdataparse[:]
            XMLdataparse[:] = []
            XMLdataparse = q.get().split('--ListBreaker--')

            if len(XMLdataparse) == 20:

                if "EventText" in XMLdataparse[0]:
                    TheCounter = len(EventTags)-1
                    for Events in reversed(EventTags):
                        try:
                            EventN = EventNames[TheCounter]
                            PlaceN = PlaceNames[TheCounter]
                            TypeN =  BetHorsessToMake[TheCounter]
                            OldTag = EventTags[TheCounter]

                            if EventN == str(XMLdataparse[2]) and PlaceN == str(XMLdataparse[3]) and TypeN == str(XMLdataparse[4]):
                                print "removing dupe: ",TypeN
                                EventTags.pop(TheCounter)
                                EventTimes.pop(TheCounter)
                                EventNames.pop(TheCounter)
                                PlaceNames.pop(TheCounter)

                            TheCounter = TheCounter - 1
                        except:
                            print "problem removing a duplicate result"

                if float(XMLdataparse[6]) > float(XMLdataparse[18]):
                    EventTags.append(XMLdataparse[0])
                    EventTimes.append(XMLdataparse[1])
                    EventNames.append(XMLdataparse[2])
                    PlaceNames.append(XMLdataparse[3])


class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    try:
                        BigSocketParse = []
                        del BigSocketParse[:]
                        BigSocketParse[:] = []
                        BigSocketParse = data.split('--MarkNew--')

                        print "Putting data in queue"
                        for eachmatch in BigSocketParse:
                            q.put(str(eachmatch))

                    except:
                        print "Unable to parse socket text."

                    #q.put(data)
                    #QCheck.start()
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()


CheckQ = Thread(target = QDUmp)
CheckQ.start()

ThreadedServer('',1234).listen()
```

The data is sent in with one larger socket using --MarkNew-- as a delimiter and I break it up to the list parts with --ListBreaker-- after that. Maybe not the most efficient way of doing things but the sockets are largely the same size as well so the slowdown has to be the way I'm dealing with the list.

Of the top of my head it's not efficient in the first place because it has to go through the whole list. But I don't know another way to get rid of the duplicates.

Any pointers on this would be really appreciated.

**Updates:**

I'd found a way to have it deal with maybe a dozen of two entries rather than a few hundred and compare the entire socket data coming in rather than each individual part but that won't do the task unfortunately. I have to be able to keep individual parts if they're new and remove the duplicates. I can't figure out a way to not have to do this.

Was considering multi threading it. It might hog resources but at least it wouldn't grind everything to a halt but the whole reason I started to use a queue was to not have multiple threads reading and writing to these lists at the same time.

**Update #2:**

Hang on...

The exception handler doesn't move TheCounter on which means it wouldn't move on properly though if that is throwing exceptions it'll throw the whole thing out of whack anyway. That might explain one or two other bugs that cropped up when it started to slow down.

Going to rework things a bit using just the one list.

I could change it to be one list and not several or only compare one entry and not three but I find it hard to believe that could be the cause of the slowdown.

**Update #3:**

Reduced it to popping from just one list. The function writing the data to the XML now copies the list first so it's working from a different one than the queue is writing to.

This has improved things but it still moves slower than I'd expect.

Comment: When I want to avoid duplicates, sets come to my mind. Any reason you don't use sets and add the incoming data to a set, so you don't have to worry about removing duplicate data?

Comment: I hadn't really looked at sets before doesn't look like it'll do what I need though. If certain bits of each socket match an existing one I need to remove everything I got from the last socket and keep everything from the new one in its place. They look pretty handy but not for this case.

Comment: I'm guessing it wouldn't be safe to thread this because I have to pop parts...

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced it down to dealing with one list and that seems to have sped it up and fixed a few other problems at the same time.

I know it looks weird but I think this is about as efficient as I'm going to be able to get it.